# Is there a Python function for allocating a mark to answers to an exam question if they include certain words?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write an automated marking system for short answer GCSE questions and have written the code to identify the correct answer if it includes certain keywords. I can print these 'correct' answers, but I want to allocate a mark to them in a new column in my dataframe. I am very new to python and programming in general and would be grateful for any help.

I've tried things along the lines of:

```
if check(sentence, words) true 
    then df['CompMark'] = 1
```

The code that I have written that identifies the correct answers is:

```
# Check if given words appear together in a list of sentence 
def check(sentence, words): 
    res = [] 
    for substring in sentence: 
        k = [ w for w in words if w in substring ] 
        if (len(k) == len(words) ): 
            res.append(substring) 
    return res

# Driver code 
sentence = df['text'] 
words = ['no','north','east'] 
print(check(sentence, words))
```

I would like it to put a '1' in a new column called 'CompMark' for each row where the keywords are included.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at least part of your problem is that after an if block in python, there should be an indent,

```
    res = [] 
    for substring in sentence: 
        k = [ w for w in words if w in substring ] 
        if (len(k) == len(words) ): 
             res.append(substring) 
    return res
```

Comment: Thank you. It is indented in Spyder, I think I just copied it wrong. I'll edit it.